# Very odd... Pi will not auto login or allow me to manually login as 'pi'

Tags: raspbian, login

I'm definitely not a newbie to *NIX but am to RPi. I just got my wireless going and was working on my touchscreen (installing drivers and the like), and needed to reboot. What came up was a username / password challenge where pi / raspberry didn't work. After a little digging    got me to a command line where I could "passwd pi" and set a password, but every time I reboot (init 6) it comes back to the challenge and doesn't take it. I can log in using user 'root' and a password that I assigned, but have lost all of my desktop apps and links.
Any way to get my auto logon as pi to work again? (or even a manual logon so I can get to my shortcuts, files, etc...)?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange Network. You don't have file-system corruption and thus a read-only root file-system do you? That will make it impossible to change things (like `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`)...!  Whilst logged in as `root` issue a `mount` command with no arguments and see what it reports about your mounted filesystems!  Of course once logged in as `root` you can then `su pi`...

Comment: Thank you SlySven. That hit me as well (to su pi and then change the password... I was changing it as root (I know... very bad practice)). On a side note I used my new Pi for a presentation tonight and it worked flawlessly and caught quite a few eyes. Only had it for two days now but seeing a ton of potential! This project has sparked anew this 55 year-old geek's nerd!

Comment: @SlySven: looks like you should post that as an answer...

Comment: @Jacobm001 Mayhaps I will if the OP tells us I *am* barking up the right tree.  My point about `su` was that once you are `root` you can become any other user ***without*** a request for THAT user's password as `root` can `su` to anyone without knowing the password (of course under normal circumstances `root` could change the password of the other (`pi`) user but that wasn't working for the OP - which would be the case if `/etc/` was on a read-only file-system...)